# How do I force expire a session if a cart_id no longer exists?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, session, devise

I implemented a shopping cart into my app.

In my `ApplicationController.rb`, I have this:

```
before_filter :initialize_cart

  def initialize_cart
    if session[:cart_id]
      @cart = Cart.find(session[:cart_id])
    else
      @cart = Cart.create
      session[:cart_id] = @cart.id
    end
  end
```

I am using Devise, and have enabled `:timeoutable`.

These are the configs in my `config/initializers/devise.rb`:

```
  # ==> Configuration for :timeoutable
  # The time you want to timeout the user session without activity. After this
  # time the user will be asked for credentials again. Default is 30 minutes.
  config.timeout_in = 30.minutes

  # If true, expires auth token on session timeout.
  config.expire_auth_token_on_timeout = true
```

The issue is that I occasionally want to sweep old carts. As it stands right now, once a cart hasn't been accessed in a while it gets deleted.

However, when the user tries to login - if they haven't cleared cookies in a while - they get this error:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound at /
Couldn't find Cart with id=51
```

I checked the session object for a timestamp of creation or update and it doesn't have one - so I can't check the state of the session and delete the session if it is past 30 minutes or whatever.

This is what the session object looks like:

```
>> session
=> {"session_id"=>"57bkhjadksjfhaksjdhfca", "cart_id"=>51, "_csrf_token"=>"3823j42&*&@#lkjM+wKkagdabskdjfhba="}
```

How do I either check to see the if the session is recent (say the user - both logged in and non-logged in - has done something in the last hour) and then destroy it if it isn't?

Or how do I fix this issue in any other way?

Comment: maybe add your own `modified` param to the cart when it's created and then see when it was last modified (created or updated)

Comment: @dax Can you give me an example of what you mean?

Comment: the timoutable model has a method `timedout?` Wouldn't that help in this case? Heres a ref link: http://rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/master/Devise/Models/Timeoutable

Comment: Not sure how to use that on non `current_user` users - i.e. users that have not logged in and so I can't call `current_user.timedout?` on. Also...if I am not mistaken, that only tracks users that have logged in. In my app, a user can add stuff to their cart without logging in first. It creates a session before they create an account. So that is what I am trying to deal with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I would do it.

```
def initialize_cart
    begin
      @cart = Cart.find(session[:cart_id])
    rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
      flash.now = "Your cart was not found." # or whatever
      @cart = Cart.create
      session[:cart_id] = @cart.id
    end
end
```

Comment: Perfect...this solves my problem. I just took out the `flash.now` because it doesn't make sense to flash them a message in this case. The rescue works though. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

at the moment, when you initialize the cart, you're doing this:

```
def initialize_cart
  if session[:cart_id] && Cart.find(session[:cart_id])
    @cart = Cart.find(session[:cart_id])
  else
    @cart = Cart.create
    session[:cart_id] = @cart.id
  end
end
```

You could, I think, try this:

```
def initialize_cart
  if session[:cart_id] && Cart.find(session[:cart_id]).exists?
    @cart = Cart.find(session[:cart_id])
  else
    @cart = Cart.create
    session[:cart_id] = @cart.id
    session[:cart_modified] = @cart.updated_at
  end
end
```

and then access the `session[:cart_modified]` param to do what you need to.  Another thing you could try (which is arguably much nicer than my first solution) is `find_or_create_by`

```
def initialize_cart
  @cart = Cart.find_or_create_by(session[:cart_id])
end
```

Comment: This looks cool and I think it will help me fix future issues. What about for all the users/visitors that have existing sessions for carts that have been deleted. How do I handle that?

Comment: sorry, how do you mean?  i think that would be handled by `if session[:cart_id]`, right?  but maybe i just don't understand :)

Comment: Well it won't be able to modify the `session` object because it won't find the `[:cart_id]` record because it doesn't exist. It has been sweeped.

Comment: right - so it will go the else part of the if statement and create a new cart for that user.  you're only removing/modifying the `:cart_id` param, not the whole session

Comment: No but the thing is, if the user has the session stored on their computer in a cookie, it will find the session which has a `cart_id` attribute. So it will pass the `if` check `if session[:cart_id]`. Then it will load the page and look for the record in the `Cart` table - which is when it returns the `not found` AR error.